# How can I get SAS to forget decimal places i variables?

Tags: formatting, sas, decimal

I have a problem with decimal places in my SAS-variables.

I have two numeric variables which I want to compare in SAS.
They are both formatted with `numx10.1` and one of the variables is calculated like this:

```
avg(delay)/30.44 as delay_months  format=numx10.1
```

I want to compare the two values in a datastep using

```
where var1^=delay_months ;
```

But even thought both variables have the same value for example. 4,1, SAS still shows this observation in the datastep with the `where-statement`.
I guess it is because of the decimals in the `delay_months` variable.

How can I get SAS to forget the decimal places and only focus on the number I see - for example 4,1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format does not change the value - it is only the way SAS represents it to you. One suggestion could be rounding during comparison (or when you create the variables)

```
where round(var1, 0.1) ^= round(delay_months, 0.1);
```

SAS uses floating-point representation for numeric values. Because of that sometimes what you see is not what it is. 
[More about that in SAS documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/69852/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0ji1unv6thm0dn1gp4t01a1u0g6.htm)